# Controlling Android ListView up and down motion

Tags: android, listview, button, scroll, controls

I would like to create two `Button` objects to control the up and down scrolling of a `ListView`.

When I click btn_up, I would like the `ListView` to scroll up.
When I click btn_down, I would like the `ListView` to scroll down.

How can I do this?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="450px" android:layout_marginTop="75px">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="844px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="180px"
            android:layout_height="450px"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_up"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_yukari" android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_down"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_asagiya" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeting sdk 8, you can use ListView function:

[smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

If your app is targeting sdk 4, you can use the following:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        your_listview.scrollTo(0, y_coordinate);
        //you can increment this value by the cell height
    }
});
```